# what version of log4net is Sitecore.Logging.dll branch/fork based upon?

Tags: logging, log4net

what version of log4net is Sitecore.Logging.dll branch/fork based upon?

There is a locking bug in log4net which affects version 1.2.10

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-298

Which was fixed in version 1.2.14 & 1.3.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-443

Looking to confirm the version that Sitecore uses, to make sure it's not affected.

Comment: I don't recall seeing the version number exposed anywhere publicly. Since it's rolled into a Sitecore assembly it would be best to submit a support ticket. Once you have your answer please specify with Sitecore version maps to the log4net version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand Sitecore initially used the same version naming for Sitecore.Logging as log4net. For example, when I look on Sitecore 6.6.0 rev. 120918 I see 1.2.0.30715. Same version is for example for 8.0 rev. 141020.

When you will look on different Sitecore.Logging assemblies on [MyGet server](https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Logging/8.1.160519) you will see that that till Sitecore 8.2, log4net version was 1.2.0.30715.

It means that if you use old Sitecore version, locking bug will be there.
For newer versions Sitecore started to use new naming convention and it is hard to identify what log4net version is baked inside.

Comment: Looking at the bug fix
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-443
"implemented the try/finally workaround mentioned in Andrii Chabykins post with svn revision 1670018"

Can see linked to this commit
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1670018
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Util/ReaderWriterLock.cs?view=markup&pathrev=1670018

This fix modifies the class "ReadWriterLock"
Which isn't even in the Sitecore.Logging.dll.

So not the same bug.